# Running Functions Simultaneously in Python

Tags: python

I have a bot for our IRC channel, and I'm trying to have it remind people what time it is while still being interactive.

The code looks like:

```
*code that logs into the server*
def process1():
    while 1:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        time = str(time).split(':')
        if '15' in time[1]:
            irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :It is %s:%s, rest of message' % (time[0],time[1]))

def process2():
    while 1:
        *code that listens and responds to what comes in from other users*

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target = process1())
    t2 = Thread(target = process2())
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t2.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

I'm thinking the issue is both processes have a

```
while 1:
```

Loop in them, and need to know how to run both while 1: loops simultaneously. I've looked at the documentation and examples for multiprocessing vs threading, along with other examples on SO and what confuses me about multiprocessing is all the examples I've seen have arguments passed onto them, where I'm just trying to run these processes that don't require any arguments.

In its simplest form: is there a way to run two functions at once, both containing while loops, independent of each other?

Comment: Yes, there is, and you already have the right idea of how to do it (using threads), but you haven't stated what exactly is the issue you're getting when trying to do it.

Comment: Seeing the full context for `while 1:`, and a traceback if one exists would help

Comment: change `t1 = Thread(target = process1())` to `t1 = Thread(target = process1)`

Comment: IRC bots are often used as the example for asynchronous programming, particularly with asyncore or tornado. Consider doing that instead of threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned in the comments by @eyllansec

I needed to change

```
t1 = Thread(target = process1())
```

to

```
t1 = Thread(target = process1)
```

Works exactly as intended now, thank you!